# Perforce - How to get Label details using Label name with wildcard

Tags: perforce

I am new to Perforce. I need a 'p4' client command to get Label(s) by providing Label name.
However I don't know complete Label name so I want to provide wildcard in the Label name.

In P4V client I do it this way:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in P4V's log pane you can see what command(s) it's running to get its data.  For labels it's probably running something like:

```
p4 labels -e "cobrands.razor*build_01"
```

Comment: P4V doesn't display commands in LOG pane for this particular case. However, your command is correct. Thank you

Comment: I was also interested in getting last 10 labels in the search result. But I notice in p4 documentation it only mentions the switch "p4 labels -m 10" for returning 1st 10 records

Comment: It probably can. If you go into P4V's preferences for Logging, and make sure that all the boxes are ticked. Specifically I think this one falls under the "Show reporting commands" ? I think?